# ng-init="loadBankNames()" ng-init() not working inside Bootstrap Model code

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I used ng-init inside Bootstrap model but it not initiating

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="loadBankNames()">  
     <option value="">Select Bank</option>  
     <option ng-repeat="b in bank_list" value="{{b.bank_name}}">{{b.bank_name}} 
     </option>   
</select>
```

```js
$scope.loadBankNames = function(){
    dmtService.getBankNames()
        .then(function(data){
        $scope.bank_list = data;
        console.log($scope.bank_list);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on `Bootstrap Model`? Did you mean `modal`?

Comment: Likely the `<div>` of the modal is outside the scope of the controller. Consider using a third-party library like [AngularUI-Bootstrap modal](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal), Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team.